# Accessing to a property of a non-static class in any place

Tags: c#, static, locking

I come today with a weird question.
Is there a way where I can use a non static class like static?

I.e:
We have the following classes:

```
public class Parameters
{
    public String LoadType { get; set; }
    public Parameters (String inLoadType)
    {
          LoadType = inLoadType;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }

    public MainClass(String inLoadType)
    {
        Parameters = new Parameters(inLoadType);
    }
}
```

Now we instantiate MainClass, then somewhere in another place that is not the MainClass I would like to access to the LoadType.

It should be threadSafe, also the operation take quite long, that is the reason I cannot simply just use a lock and make it static.

The class where I want to access that variable is static, I thought in a workaround with a static Event in the Parameters class, and whoever call the event would get the value of the instantiated class or something like that.
Any other Ideas about it beside passing as parameter to the static method what I need?

Sounds like stupid question but I just want to know if is possible or not.

Comment: You need a singleton.

Comment: Yes singleton class will work here

Comment: Singleton would be static if I want to access outside the MainClass,then it would not be threadsafe. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are. Thread safety and static/non static classes are two different concepts. @TareqB.

Comment: A singleton doesn't have to be static. But to use it within a class it must be provided as a dependency either in the constructor of that class or passed to it in a method call. Although I'd advocate constructor dependency in this case.

Comment: Of course are two differents things, but in my case if one of the threads changes instantiate the main class with the parameter class and uses the singleton, any other thread that has instantiated the class would get the static parameter property override.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it well.

LoadType would load data from the DB, Path or Resources.

When I instantiate MainClass in a Thread I will tell how to make the LoadType for that single moment, for that single thread. Another Thread can have a different LoadType.

I will have to use the LoadType in a static class where I don't have the MainClass in the parameters.

Knowing that, if I use Singleton as mentioned before in comments, when I  access to the value in the method, it may that other thread has changed this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine, that you have *two* `Parameters` instances

```
  Parameters one = new Parameters("One");
  Parameters two = new Parameters("Two");
```

and then you call:

```
  String result = SomeWeirdBlackMagicCallOfLoadType();
```

What is the expected result? `"One"` or `"Two"`? In order to solve this
problem, you can turn `Parameters` into *singletone* (one instance only) and thus the call will be

```
  String result = Parameters.Instance.LoadType;
```

but I suggest treating `static` as `static` when data doesn't depend on instance. In case of *long* operations, *thread safety* you can use `Lazy<String>` which is specially designed for that:

```
  public class Parameters {
    private static Lazy<String> s_LoadType = new Lazy<string>(() => {
      ....
      return "bla-bla-bla";
    });

    public static String LoadType {
      get {
        return s_LoadType.Value;
      }
    }
    ... 
  }
```